# Upload large video via NSURLSession causes memory pressure crash

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, nsdata, nsurlsession

I use the following codes to upload video to server, which requires me to convert the video from video format to `NSData`. However, when the video is large (e.g. 10 minute video), the App crashes due to memory pressure. How can I resolve this?

```
- (void)uploadVideo {
    NSDictionary *params = nil;
    NSString *NSURLSessionIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"my.bundle.identifier.",[self getTimeString]];
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig;
    // SessionConfiguration With iOS Version
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) {
        sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:NSURLSessionIdentifier];
    } else {
        sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:NSURLSessionIdentifier];
    }
    sessionConfig.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1;

    NSURLSession *uploadSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue new]];
    OMGMultipartFormData *multipartFormData = [OMGMultipartFormData new];

    NSString *url = @"SOME_UPLOAD_URL";
    // ========= PROBLEMATIC LINE below =========
    self.video_data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.video_url];
    // ========= PROBLEMATIC LINE above =========
    [multipartFormData addFile:self.video_data parameterName:@"file" filename:@"file.mp4" contentType:@"video/mp4"];

    NSURLRequest *rq = [OMGHTTPURLRQ POST:url:multipartFormData];
    id path = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"upload.NSData"];
    [rq.HTTPBody writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    [[uploadSession uploadTaskWithRequest:rq fromFile:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]] resume];

}
```

p.s. `self.video_url` is a file URL given by `UIImagePickerController` which filters only video to choose. I then choose a 10-minute video.

p.s. I got `AFNetworking` in same App too, can it help with background transfer?

Comment: You need to divide video into 2mb part and then upload those part to server.

Comment: I guess so, but how to modify my upload code to add 2MB chunks?

Comment: You need to send Base64 Send to server with part number and server can gather all part once it's complete all parts then it's all base64 convert into mp4

Comment: Why are you trying to load whole video in memory and send it? It's perfectly normal that your app crashes. 
All files should be send using multipart/form-data which will ensure your app from memory crash while uploading. AFnetworking has done it pretty easy.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to this by using a [NSMutableURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/) and utilizing its [setHTTPBodyStream](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSMutableURLRequest/HTTPBodyStream) setter.

The following are snippets adapted from some code of mine. It handled well for video way over 10 mins. mostly large videos of 60 - 90 minutes.

```
NSData *movieData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:theMovieSourceString];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"video/quicktime" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"attachment; filename=\"%@\"",yourMovieSourceString] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Disposition"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(unsigned long)[movieData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBodyStream:[NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:yourMovieSourceString]];
```

You can now use this request with your [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLConnection/initWithRequest:delegate:)

```
NSURLConnection *connection =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Comment: This can't work in background mode, where connection will be disconnected.

Comment: I have exact memory usage compared to InputStream(data: data), plus with method above sending speed is significantly slower.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is obvious - 10 min video file is too big to be stored in a memory what

```
self.video_data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.video_url];
```

does.

Solution is not to store all request body in a memory. The simplest way is to use NSURLRequest's [HTTPBodyStream](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLRequest/HTTPBodyStream) property. You can create NSInputStream yourself but since you already have AFNetworking it is much easier to use it. In my project I do it this way:

```
// data.fields is a dictionary with params

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]
                                multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                URLString:[url absoluteString]
                                parameters:nil
                                constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
                                {
                                    [data.fields enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
                                        [formData appendPartWithFormData:[obj dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] name:key];
                                    }];
                                    [formData appendPartWithFileURL:fileURL name:@"file_0" error:&error2];
                                }
                                error:&error];
```